# How to use google-cloud-os-config classes in python code?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

In a Google Cloud function (python 3.7) , I need to fetch the compliance state of all VMs in a given location in a project.
From available google documentation here I could see the REST API format:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/os-configuration-management/view-compliance#view_compliance_state

On searching for the client library [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/osconfig/latest/osconfig_v1alpha/types.html) , I found this:

```
class google.cloud.osconfig_v1alpha.types.ListInstanceOSPoliciesCompliancesRequest(mapping=None, *, ignore_unknown_fields=False, **kwargs)[source]
Bases: proto.message.Message

A request message for listing OS policies compliance data for all Compute Engine VMs in the given location.

parent
Required. The parent resource name.

Format: projects/{project}/locations/{location}

For {project}, either Compute Engine project-number or project-id can be provided.

Type
str

page_size
The maximum number of results to return.

Type
int

page_token
A pagination token returned from a previous call to ListInstanceOSPoliciesCompliances that indicates where this listing should continue from.

Type
str

filter
If provided, this field specifies the criteria that must be met by a InstanceOSPoliciesCompliance API resource to be included in the response.

Type
str
```

And the response class as:

```
class google.cloud.osconfig_v1alpha.types.ListInstanceOSPoliciesCompliancesResponse(mapping=None, *, ignore_unknown_fields=False, **kwargs)[source]
Bases: proto.message.Message

A response message for listing OS policies compliance data for all Compute Engine VMs in the given location.

instance_os_policies_compliances
List of instance OS policies compliance objects.

Type
Sequence[google.cloud.osconfig_v1alpha.types.InstanceOSPoliciesCompliance]

next_page_token
The pagination token to retrieve the next page of instance OS policies compliance objects.

Type
str

property raw_page
```

But I am not sure how to use this information in the python code.

I have written this but not sure if this is correct:

```
from google.cloud.osconfig_v1alpha.services.os_config_zonal_service import client
from google.cloud.osconfig_v1alpha.types import ListInstanceOSPoliciesCompliancesRequest
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
import os

def handler():
    try: 
        project_id = os.environ["PROJECT_ID"]
        location = os.environ["ZONE"]

        #list compliance state
        request = ListInstanceOSPoliciesCompliancesRequest(
            parent=f"projects/{project}/locations/{location}")
        response = client.instance_os_policies_compliance(request)
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Unable to get compliance - %s " % str(e))
```

I could not find any usage example for the client library methods anywhere.
Could someone please help me here?

**EDIT:**

This is what I am using now:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

def list_policy_compliance():
    projectId = "my_project"
    zone = "my_zone"
    try:
        service = build('osconfig', 'v1alpha', cache_discovery=False)
        compliance_response = service.projects().locations(
            ).instanceOsPoliciesCompliances().list(
                parent='projects/%s/locations/%s' % (
                    projectId, zone)).execute()
        return compliance_response
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception()
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```py
from google.cloud import os_config_v1alpha as osc

def handler():
    client = osc.OsConfigZonalService()
    project_id = "my_project"
    location = "my_gcp_zone"
    parent = f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}"

    response = client.list_instance_os_policies_compliances(
        parent=parent
    )

    # response is an iterable yielding 
    # InstanceOSPoliciesCompliance objects 
    for result in response:
        # do something with result
        ...
```

You can also construct the request like this:

```py
response = client.list_instance_os_policies_compliances(
    request = {
        "parent": parent
    }
)
```

Comment: I used a code that I have edited in the question and its working fine for me now. Thank you for your response .

Comment: What you've got works, though I'd definitely encourage using the google.cloud libraries. You'll get a better feature set out of the box (retries, pagination, ...) and a consistent surface/usage patterns across all the Cloud APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here , this is what I used:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

def list_policy_compliance():
    projectId = "my_project"
    zone = "my_zone"
    try:
        service = build('osconfig', 'v1alpha', cache_discovery=False)
        compliance_response = service.projects().locations(
            ).instanceOsPoliciesCompliances().list(
                parent='projects/%s/locations/%s' % (
                    projectId, zone)).execute()
        return compliance_response
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception()
```